# Diff between a pipe and a filter?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting and I want to know what the difference is between pipe and filter.
They both seem to do the same things. Even the format is the same.

```
ls -l | grep user |cat >user
```

A pipe or a filter?

Comment: The *pipe* is just the `|` that connects the output of one program to the input of the next. A *filter* is any program which performs some operation on data received via stdin and outputs the "filtered" data via stdout.

Comment: A filter is a kind of pipe. If a process taking part in a pipe simply echos some subset of its stdin to stdout, it's a filter.

Comment: Note also that you have a [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) in your example above.

Comment: Unable to re-edit this Q: The Q is `Is the above command a pipe or a filter?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the whole command is a pipeline:

```
 ls -l | grep user | cat > user
```

`ls` is acting as the source of data. `grep` is then acting as a filter - a filter performs some kind of transformation on the data. The pipe (`|`) passes the data from `ls` to `grep`, performing buffering etc. Finally `cat` (which is extraneous in your example) outputs the filtered data to something (terminal, file, variable).

Comment: You could argue that `cat` is a filter which simply performs an identity operation. (In its useful use, it catenates files, of course.)

Answer (score 8):

The graph below briefly describes the relationship of `pipe`, `filter`, `pipeline` and `redirection`.

[image: pipeline]

`Filter` is only one **ELEMENT** of a `pipeline`, all the elements in `pipeline` are collected by `pipe`. Below is the definition of `Filter` in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29).

> In Unix and Unix-like operating systems, a filter is a program that gets most of its data from its standard input (the main input stream) and writes its main results to its standard output (the main output stream). Unix filters are often used as elements of pipelines. The pipe operator ("|") on a command line signifies that the main output of the command to the left is passed as main input to the command on the right.